# How use read.table in a for loop?

Tags: r

I want to use `read.table` in a `for` loop, and do some analysis on each data at a time, and write the results to a matrix. The file names have the following pattern `AA.BB.CC.P1.DD` , `AA.BB.CC.P2.DD` , etc.

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:8) {
  assign( paste("AA.BB.CC.P", i, sep="") 
    data <- read.table(paste(i, "DD", sep="."))

a <- data$V7
b <- data$V12
c <- data$V13
d <- data$V15

function(a,b,c,d)
  }
```

I get this error:

`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '1.DD': No such file or directory`

Comment: Your code is trying to read a nonexistent file `data <- read.table(paste(i, "DD", sep="."))`, hence `1.DD, 2.DD, ...` Is that really the filenames it wants to read?

Comment: @Jaap. No, considering the replies, now it gets the file names, but not the `data$V7`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is gibberish. Don't use a `for` loop here. It would be easiest to put all the files in one directory and then do something like this:

```
ff <- list.files(path="<add your dir path here>", full.names=TRUE)
#use the pattern argument, if you have files in the directory, 
#   which you don't want to read in

myfilelist <- lapply(ff, read.table)
names(myfilelist) <- list.files(path="<add your dir path here>", full.names=FALSE)
```

This gives you a nice list with data.frames, which is much easier to work with than a lot of objects in your workspace.

Comment: How do you define the header for each file? I try to pass it to `read.table`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Would that work for you? (I'm not sure what are you doing with `function(a,b,c,d)`)

```
for(i in 1:8) {

  data <- read.table(paste0("AA.BB.CC.P",i,".", "DD"))

          a <- data$V7
          b <- data$V12
          c <- data$V13
          d <- data$V15

          function(a,b,c,d)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it does not read each file at a time for the purpose of function. It says `Error in data$V7 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Answer (score 3):

This answer builds upon Roland's answer.

To iterate over items in a file, and read them into tables, you can use Roland's codes. He passes a read.table function into lapply.

The issue is that you can't pass non default parameters into the read.table function.

The code below creates a function that sets header = False and sep = ',', but you can change that and personalize your own function (this solves user2162153's question).

```
#Building up on Roland's answer, you can pass a personalized reader function. First define your function and than use his codes. 

Personalized_Reader <- function(lambda){
 read.table(lambda, header = FALSE ,sep = ',')}


# Personalize your arguments on the read.table function

ff <- list.files(path="<add your dir path here>", full.names=TRUE)
#use the pattern argument, if you have files in the directory, which you don't want to read in

myfilelist <- lapply(ff, Personalized_Reader)

names(myfilelist) <- list.files(path="<add your dir path here>", full.names=FALSE)
```

`

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?  Blocks of code are always much more informative with an explanation to go with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i in 1:8) {

  data <- read.table(paste("AA.BB.CC.P",i,".DD"))

          a <- data$V7
          b <- data$V12
          c <- data$V13
          d <- data$V15

          function(a,b,c,d)
}
```

the problem in your code was that with

```
data <- read.table(paste(i, "DD", sep="."))
```

the source of data is only "i.DD" and not "AA.BB.CC.P.i,DD"... you should define the format of file to read too? for example .csv
If you still have this problem check the path of your file and your actually working directory
(use this: "getwd()" to check your actually wd)

Comment: Thanks! Now, it gets the file name correctly, but does not accept `data$V7` ,etc.

Comment: you must check the header of your data, use 
colnames(data)
and use that field

Comment: The individual files do not have header.

Comment: try with 

data[,x]

where x is the number of coulmn you are looking for, ex:

a <- data[,7]
b <- data[,12]

and so on...